# R - Twitter - OAuth - REST API - User cannot be authenticated

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

I have code that previously worked for authenticating me, but no longer does.  Has something changed that I missed?

The way I authenticate is as follows

```
library(httr)
options(httr_oauth_cache=TRUE)

myKey = "x123y456z789"
mySecret = "a987b654c321"
myToken = "abc123456def" 
tokenSecret = "zxy987654"

myapp = oauth_app("Twitter", key=myKey, secret=mySecret)
sig = sign_oauth1.0(myapp, token=myToken, token_secret=tokenSecret)
```

I build a simple search query to test

```
BASE = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?"
query = "q=13+Reasons+Why"
url = paste( BASE, query, sep="")
```

This makes the final, basic URL with no date, time, tweet limits, etc...

```
url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=13+Reasons+Why"

GET(url, sig)
```

Returns

```
Response [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=13+Reasons+Why]
Date: 2017-05-13 19:42
Status: 401
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Size: 64 B
```

Wrapping that in content

```
content( GET(url, sig) )
```

Tells me

```
$errors[[1]]$message
[1] "Could not authenticate you."
```

I've checked all my tokens, secrets, etc are correct, and the query is so simple that I'm not sure where it can be going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```
library(httr)
myKey = "x123y456z789:"
mySecret = "a987b654c321"
myapp = oauth_app("Twitter", key=myKey, secret=mySecret)
token = oauth1.0_token(app = myapp, endpoint = oauth_endpoints("twitter"))
BASE = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"
q = "13 Reasons why"
res <- GET(BASE, config(token = token), query = list(q=q))
t(sapply(content(res)$statuses[1:3], "[", c("created_at", "text")))
#      created_at                       text                                                                                                             
# [1,] "Sat May 13 19:58:03 +0000 2017" "Stuck on episode 11 of 13 reasons why I don't have the heart to finish it it's so sad <f0><U+009F><" [truncated]
# [2,] "Sat May 13 19:58:01 +0000 2017" "RT @SelenaGomezNews: New photo of Selena Gomez on set of '13 Reasons Why'. "             
# [3,] "Sat May 13 19:58:00 +0000 2017" "RT @lockscreenbabes: <U+2615> katherine langford and dylan minette (13 reasons why) lockscreen <U+2" [truncated]
```

Comment: Greetings. Thanks. I'm still getting an issue. Immediately after doing " token = oauth1.0_token( app=myapp, endpoint=oauth_endpoints("twitter") ) I get an unauthorized HTTP 401 error.   Could this be due to your "Twitter" in myapp be coming from something that must be named as such that I'm missing?

Comment: @Jibril My guess would be: myKey and mySecret are wrong. (That's when I get the error.)

Comment: Thanks.  I thought so too, but I've checked like 30 times.  I've re-copied them over from Twitter, and still nothing.  I did manage to get a Direct Connection once using them using the twitteR package once, but I'd rather continue using httr and the way I am currently doing it, as most of my parsing code is already designed for that.

Comment: @Jibril  Did you take "Consumer Key (API Key)" and "Consumer Secret (API Secret)" from your apps' developer page? Did you make any changes since you got the key+secret pair (e.g. changed permissions etc.)? If the latter is the case, you might want to generate a new pair. (I had that issue once.)

Comment: Thanks again, I think you're onto something. While I don't think I changed anything, regenerating the keys now produces a new error for me to diagnose - "  token = oauth1.0_token(app = myapp, endpoint = oauth_endpoints("twitter"))
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘openssl’ ", but this is progress, as its no longer just rejecting authentication!

Comment: Though, installing library(openssl) sends me right back to the "Unauthorized" error again, so who knows afterall.

Comment: @Jibril Did you restart R (clean session, reloading httr or maybe even reinstalling it beforehand)? Sometimes this works wonder.

Comment: I actually did. In a fit of frustration after the previous attempt not working, I uninstalled R from my PC entirely, re-installed fresh, re-installed the HTTR package, and am right back to where I was with the Unauthorized.  Regenerated my keys 3 more times since then, and still same issue everytime.  Beyond frustrated on what this could be, as its like 4 lines of code lol

Comment: @Jibril Strange. Fwiw, my `sessionInfo()`, under which it seems to be working, is R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) running under Windows 7 x64 httr_1.2.1, R6_2.2.0, tools_3.3.2, curl_2.5, Rcpp_0.12.10, httpuv_1.3.3, openssl_0.9.6.

Comment: I'll consider trying to replicate those conditions if no one else pops in with better ideas.   Primary differences I suppose is R 3.4.0, curl_2.6 R6_2.2.1

Comment: Not sure if its related, but on the develop page for the app where I get my API key, if I click the "Test OAuth" button, it also fails there.  Get a "Sorry! This page doesn't exist" from Twitter.

Comment: @Jibril I get that 404 error, too. And my apps' callback url is http://127.0.0.1:1410 . The app has read & write permissions.

Comment: Yeah I set my callback URL to that as well as per a thread I saw on the Twitter forum page.  Mine is read/write/DMs, but I just changed to read/write only and regenerated key. No dice. :/ They really need more specific error messages -_-

Comment: @Jibril Ok I must pass. If noone answers, maybe post a new question that includes package versions and what you all tried up to now. I don't understand the error. `oauth1.0_token` should send you to your default internet browser and allow your/your twitter user to grant permissions to your app. After that, you should have a valid token and thus "authorization" to query the api within the api rate limits.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I got your code to work. Just wanted to add a final comment and accept.  My callback URL was changed to my universities URL, matching my "website" for my app.  This seemingly did the trick. I am not sure why using the recommended 127.0.0.1:1410 that I saw everywhere worked, but it didn't.  Thanks for your help.